# Multiple GRUB entries in BBS options

Tags: arch-linux, boot, grub

I wanted to reinstall my arch installation. I was having GRUB installed only to boot Arch and my Windows installation has its own seperate bootloader. 
Im using an efi-partition at the beginning of the disk for both of the loaders. 
After reinstalling arch (formatting arch partition), I thought I should reinstall grub too (without removing the old one first). Now I've two boot options in my efi and neither one of them is booting arch, saying that the UUID of the root partition is wrong. 
How can I uninstall these GRUBs so I can do a fresh install?